# How to simulate audio and video calls in NS3?

Tags: network-programming, ns2, ns-3

I want to generate different types of traffic for analyzing OFDMA transmission in NS3. How can I simulate video and audio calls?

Comment: **ns3** : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-3-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first three options that come to mind are:

1. If you want to be as close to reality as possible, try out the [Direct Code Execution (DCE) Module](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/dce/manual/html/getting-started.html). I've never used it, so I'm not sure how well it's supported.
2. Use the [`OnOffApplication`](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_on_off_application.html). The `OnOffApplication` allows you to set `onTime`, `offTime`, and a `DataRate` (among other variables). You can determine the rate at which data is sent for your audio or video program, and then provide those rates to the `OnOffApplication`. You may find the [`OnOffHelper`](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_on_off_helper.html) convenient to set various parameters of an `OnOffApplication`.
3. Create your own `Application`. This option may be of particular interest since you could simulate variable bitrate audio/video calls. If you choose this option, I highly suggest you checkout the ns-3 tutorial for the [walkthrough of `fifth.cc`](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/tutorial/html/tracing.html#walkthrough-fifth-cc) to learn more about how to create your own `Application`.

The second option is probably easiest to use, but may not be as accurate as the first, or as flexible as the third.